# Can I create a workbook with Excel javascript add in?

Tags: excel, office-js

Is there any equivalent for Excel javascript add-ins to do what we can do in Word with context.application.createDocument() ? I don't see any create method in Excel Application object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API for Excel is now under previewing, you can try to call through this way: context.application.createWorkbook(base64);

Comment: Thanks, do I need to enable some kind of preview functionality? Because for the moment I get "Object doesn't support property or method 'createWorkbook'" when doing that.

Comment: It worked. That said, would it be too much to ask for the possibility to decide on the name of the created files? ;) - I see it's not available, but consider it a feature request. My scenario is that I want to split an excel into multiple ones based on a discriminator column (let's say one per country).

Answer (score 2):

As @MSFT-Jipyua mentioned, `createWorkbook()` is currently in "Preview" as part of [v1.8](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/ExcelJs_OpenSpec/reference/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets.md). As it is in preview Preview (1.7 was just [released in May](https://dev.office.com/blogs/excel-javascript-api-1-7-goes-ga) and is rolling out to clients now) so keep in mind that this API won't work with all builds and platforms supported by Excel.

In order to call this API, you need to use the beta library release. This is hosted at `https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js`. You'll need to switch any references to the production library (`https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js`) to the beta library in order to access preview functionality.

Comment: Also, your best bet will be to be on the [Insider build of Office](https://products.office.com/en-us/office-insider), to make sure that you have the latest version of Office that will support the APIs.

Comment: Side-note, @Marc:  As for the 1.7 APIs, they *are* out:  see https://dev.office.com/blogs/excel-javascript-api-1-7-goes-ga for more info

Comment: using the beta link did the trick. I didn't need to get into insider program. I am on build 1804. Interesting thing:  if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('ExcelApi', 1.7) === true) gave true. 1.8 didn't. But the requested operation is there :)

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft  You're right, I should have been a little clearer. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @tec-goblin, this is actually expected.  Beta APIs are specifically shown as not being part of an officially supported set, since the APIs may change or be  renamed/postponed/moved etc.

Comment: Any updates 4 years later? Need to open a second workbook in memory and copy/paste custom charts from there to another workbook. Anything like this possible or nothing changed since 2018 ?

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2020**

There is a method you can simply use for creating a new Excel Workbook

```
Excel.createWorkbook()
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-workbooks#create-a-workbook